# Vim cannot be commented correctly with multiple quotation marks

Tags: vim

I found a bug in the vim language syntax of <vim.vim> file.  If there are multiple quotation marks in a comment, it will not be treated as normal comment.  For example:

[image: a vim script example with comments]

the line 1 and line 3 will not be commented as I expected.

How can I fix the bug ? I try to understand the syntax setting in the of vimComment setting and do some modification, but failed.

---

### Add more details about my question:

I wrote a vim script as below:

```
  let a = b    " b range:0~255
```

Note: there are some spaces at the beginning of the statement.

I want to comment this statement, so add quotation at the beginning of the statement.

```
  " let a = b    " b range:0~255
```

I find the statement will NOT be recognized as `vimComment` as I expected, it will be treated as `vimString` (when cursor under let) and `vimIsCommand` (when cursor under range).

Here, I used the following method to check syntax name and definition under cursor.

```
nnoremap <f8> :echo synIDattr(synID(line('.'), col('.'), 0), 'name')<cr>
```

I think this is a bug in the `vim.vim` file which version is '8.0-28'.

Comment: Please include the sample in your question, formatted as code. Images of text are not useful.

Comment: @KeithThompson The advantage of an image in this particular case is to show colors. The question is about wrong syntax highlighting in comments.

Comment: Then please *also* include it in your question, formatted as code, along with a description of what it looks like. It wasn't clear from your question that you were asking about syntax highlighting; I thought you were saying the code isn't executed correctly (say, if you type `:source vim.vim`).

Comment: I've added some formatting markup and corrected some typos. Please verify that I didn't break anything.

Comment: You are confusing Stack Overflow with [an issue tracker](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues).

Comment: Line 1 is probably what we want anyway. Line 3 works on my machine: 

:version
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.1 (2018 May 18, compiled Apr 15 2020 06:40:31)

Comment: `let a = b    " let a = b "  b range: 0~255`  You can try this script statement in you VIM. I found the strings after the first quotation were not in the state of comment.

Comment: What do you get with `:set filetype`  ?

Comment: no pblm with version 8.2.2815

Answer (score 1):

For received feedbacks that there were no the same issue found in the others' VIM enviroment, I had to check my settings and did some trials. In the end I found this issue was caused by the `Plugin 'thaerkh/vim-indentguides'`. If I did not use this plugin, the comment state was correct as I expected. I guess the plugin has some errors in using of VIM conceal feature. So I changed to use the `Plugin 'Yggdroot/indentLine'` instead and solved the issue. Thank @all.